# How programmatically sort glazedList table ascendant acording second column?

Tags: java, jtable, swingworker, glazedlists

I have a GlazedList table which has 3 columns. I can sort decedent and ascendant manually by clicking on the header of columns.

**My question is how to sort the table from begin when application start up?** 
I means the table be ascendant sorted automatically according second column.

```
 // Build a filter
    FilterList<Code> radioFilterList = new FilterList<Code>(CodeModel.getCodeEventList(), new ThreadedMatcherEditor<Code>(filterPanel.getCodeMatcherEditor()));
    TextFilterator<Code> CodeTextFilterator = new TextFilterator<Code>() {
        public void getFilterStrings(java.util.List<String> strings, Code Code) {
            strings.add(Code.getName());
            strings.add(String.valueOf(Code.getDate()));
            strings.add(String.valueOf(Code.getSize()));
        }
    };
    MatcherEditor<Code> textMatcherEditor = new TextComponentMatcherEditor<Code>(filterPanel.getTextComponent(), CodeTextFilterator);
    filterList = new FilterList<Code>(radioFilterList, new ThreadedMatcherEditor<Code>(textMatcherEditor));

    // Build a JTable
    String[] propertyNames = new String[]{"name", "date", "size"};
    String[] columnLabels = new String[]{"Code Name", "Code Date", "Size"};
    TableFormat<Code> tableFormat = GlazedLists.tableFormat(Code.class, propertyNames, columnLabels);
    CodeSortedList = new SortedList<Code>(filterList, null);
    CodeTable = new JTable(new EventTableModel<Code>(CodeSortedList, tableFormat));
    TableComparatorChooser.install(CodeTable, CodeSortedList, TableComparatorChooser.MULTIPLE_COLUMN_MOUSE);

    // Configure the JTable
    CodeTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    CodeTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

**Edited:**
Just add `.appendComparator(1,0,true)` to the `TableComparatorChooser` as below.

`TableComparatorChooser.install(codeTable, codeSortedList, TableComparatorChooser.MULTIPLE_COLUMN_MOUSE).appendComparator(1,0,true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.appendComparator(1,0,true)` to the `TableComparatorChooser` as below.

```
TableComparatorChooser.install(codeTable, codeSortedList, TableComparatorChooser.MULTIPLE_COLUMN_MOUSE).appendComparator(1,0,true);
```